# My recently formatted laptop is taking too long to boot, how to improve it?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot

I have a Dell Inspiron 15R SE, its configuration:

1. Intel Core i7-3632QM 2.2 gHz
2. 8GB DDR3
3. Wi-Fi 802.11 b/g/n/ Bluetooth 4.0/ USB 3.0/ RJ-45
4. 1 TB HDD + 32 GB SSD(mSata)

I just formatted it 5 times last 24h, all those times the best booting time was about 5 minutes, *5 MINUTES to a recently formatted laptop* with that configuration!

I have bought it 2 years ago, and used quite a lot, but **never dropped it on the ground or damaged it**.

MY SSD is currently with problems you can view another post I made here:
[How can I restore RAID 0 on my DELL laptop?](https://superuser.com/questions/744322/how-can-i-restore-raid-0-on-my-dell-laptop)

So, depending ONLY on my HDD, it shouldn't take too long to boot!

My read and write speed its OK, its getting up to 45Mb/s, and writing about 30Mb/s.

I have absolute nothing besides the O.S on my HDD and its taking this long to boot, what can it be?

Comment: What part of booting process takes most time or where does it get hung up?

Comment: It's not an ideal solution, but I would contact the DELL customer support line and see if they can supply you with a set of factory recovery discs.

Comment: How do you know that the HDD is the problem? If you don't know for sure then why do you keep formatting it instead of doing more troubleshooting? Is it POST that is slow or is it slow to get to the logon screen after POST is completed?

Comment: @tumchaaditya It doesn't hung up, it just takes a long time at windows logo (before login window)

Comment: @MichaelFrank I would do that but my warranty is over, I can't basically contact then, I tried opening a community ticket but no answer in 2 weeks now

Comment: @joeqwerty it might not be HDD, but I have no clue what is! The massive formatting wasn't for trying to correct the boot problem, it was in order to fix my SSD (which got no results)

Comment: OK. Understood. I would move on from the HDD and start looking at other things. How long does it take for POST to complete?

Comment: If the POST to complete is after login (which I didn't set a password so it can be faster), it takes about 1 minute. (the longer wait is on windows animated logo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like its hanging on initialising some hardware. Try unplugging every USB device except the ones you really need (read: keyboard and mouse).

Boot the pc and see if the boot times improve.

Optionally, try booting into safe mode, and see how fast it gets booted this way.

Make sure you install your chipset drivers and graphics card drivers and all other drivers that haven't been installed.

If after this the problem still exists, let us know what the outcome of each test was.

Comment: Perhaps trying to load SSD is what is causing the problem, since its faulty and buggy, but how can I disable SSD from loading?

Comment: I figured from your other post that it is a hybrid one, correct? I'm not sure how you could disconnect one of those to be honest. Maybe there's a jumper on the device itself? If it are 2 separate drives, maybe you can disconnect the SSD part.

Comment: LoL! I just went to device manager and disabled my SSD, rebooted and it took 30 seconds to boot '-', THANKS. But that also means my SSD is fuc*ed up right?

Comment: It could mean that, but it doesn't have to be. If there's a conflct in the drivers it can cause the exact same behavior.

Comment: HMM, nice thought, but how can I know if the driver is right or not?

Comment: Thats hard to figure out, but basically if you look for the right driver and you install it, and it doesn't change the behavior, the drive is dead. If there is a problem with the driver, you see any kind of change. Either it fixes it, or at least you notice errors or other weird behavior.